# List recursion base case

Tags: lisp

```
(cond ((null list) nil) ;This is true if we are not at the end of the list?
```

while

```
(cond ((null lst) '()) ; this means we are at the empty set?
```

Not quite sure how these are different, can anyone help?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

They aren't different. `nil` and `'()` denote exactly the same object in Lisp:

```
[1]> (eq nil '())
T
```

Some people will tell you to use `nil` to denote the boolean false, and `'()` or `()` for the empty list. That's just a matter of coding style, though.

Comment: Hmm, I actually think I might have misunderstood (cond()).

for the first case, if the list is empty, it answers will nil, and for the other case, if the list is empty, it answers with the empty set, is that correct? Thanks! 

And for your answer I understand that '() and nil are basically the same?

Comment: @GregorioDiStefano: `()` is the empty *list*, not empty *set*. Otherwise, correct.